# GNS Construction Proof

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I am currently reading through the proof of the GNS Construction, and there are two parts I simply do not understand. Below is the *entire* proof, the parts in red are what I do **not** understand. It would be great if someone could clear these up for me.

---

Let $A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra with $f\colon A\to\mathbb{C}$ a positive linear functional. Define
$$
N=\{a\in A: f(a^\ast a)=0\}.
$$
Note that $N$ is not only a vector subspace of $A$, but a left ideal as well. In particular, $A/N$ is a vector space. We let $\xi\colon A\to A/N$ be the quotient map. We have chosen $N$ so that
$$
\langle\xi(a),\xi(b)\rangle:=f(b^\ast a)
$$
is a well-define inner product on $A/N$. Therefore we can complete $A/N$ to a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Since $N$ is a left-ideal in $A$, for each $a\in A$ we can define an operator $\pi_0(a)$ on $A/N$ by
$$
\pi_0(a)\xi(b):=\xi(ab).
$$
Furthermore, $\pi_0$ is a homomorphism of $A$ into the linear operators on $A/N$.

Since $a^\ast a\leq\|a\|^2\mathbf{1}_{\tilde{A}}$, we have $b^\ast a^\ast ab\leq\|a^2\|b^\ast b$ for any $a,b\in A$.

Therefore
$$
\|\pi_0(a)\xi(b)\|^2=\|\xi(ab)\|^2=f(b^\ast a^\ast ab)\leq\|a\|^2f(b^\ast b)=\|a\|^2\|\xi(b)\|^2.
$$
It follows that $\pi_0(a)$ is bounded and extends to an operator $\pi(a)$ on $\mathcal{H}$. Clearly, $\pi\colon A\to B(\mathcal{H})$ is an algebra homeomorphism. Since
$$
\langle\pi_0(a)\xi(b),\xi(c)\rangle=f(c^\ast ab)=\langle\xi(b),\pi_0(a^\ast)\xi(c)\rangle,
$$
we must have $\pi(a)^\ast=\pi(a^\ast)$. Thus $\pi$ is a representation.

Now let $\{e_\lambda\}$ be an approximate identity in $A$. If $\mu\leq\lambda$, then $e_\lambda-e_\mu\geq0$ and $\left(\mathbf{1}_{\tilde{A}}-(e_\lambda-e_\mu)\right)\geq0$. This implies that $\|e_\lambda-e_\mu\|\leq1$. Thus, $(e_\lambda-e_\mu)^2\leq(e_\lambda-e_\mu)$ and
$$
\|\xi(e_\lambda)-\xi(e_\mu)\|^2=f\left((e_\lambda-e_\mu)^2\right)\leq f\left((e_\lambda-e_\mu)\right).
$$
Since $\lim_\lambda f(e_\lambda)=\|f\|=\lim_\mu f(e_\mu)$, $\{\xi(e_\lambda)\}$ is a Cauchy net in $\mathcal{H}$. Hence, there is a $h\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $\xi(e_\lambda)\to h$.

This means that
$$
\pi(a)h=\lim_\lambda\pi_0(a)\xi(e_\lambda)=\lim_\lambda\xi(ae_\lambda).
$$
But $a\mapsto\xi(a)$ is continous because $f$ is: $\|\xi(a)-\xi(b)\|^2=f\left((b-a)^\ast(b-a)\right)$. So we can conclude that $\pi(a)h=\xi(a)$. $\color{red}{\text{Therefore }h\text{ is a cyclic vector for }\pi}$ and
$$
\langle\pi(a^\ast a)h,h\rangle=\langle\pi(a)h,\pi(a)h\rangle=\langle\xi(a),\xi(a)\rangle=f(a^\ast a).
$$
$\color{red}{\text{By linearity, } f(a)=\langle\pi(a)h,h\rangle\text{ for all }a\in A}$.

Since $\pi$ has a cyclic vector, it is definitely nondegenerate, so $\pi(e_\lambda)h\to h$. Thus
$$
\|f\|=\lim_\lambda f(e_\lambda)=\lim_\lambda\langle\pi(e_\lambda)h,h\rangle=\|h\|^2.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First red part:

You have $\xi(a)=\pi(a)h$. By construction, the image of $\xi$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. In other words, $\pi(A)h$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ which means exactly that $h$ is cyclic for $\pi$.

Second red part:

The elements of the form $a^*a$ are exactly the positive elements. Every element in a $C^*$-algebra is a linear combination of four positive elements, so indeed you can use linearity on the line above the claim.

Comment: So what you are saying is that $h$ is cyclic for $\pi$ if 
$$
\overline{\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}}=\mathcal{H}.
$$
Which we have, as you said. The definition I have is that $h$ is cyclic for $\pi$ if
$$
\overline{\text{span}}\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}=\mathcal{H}.
$$
But, since we know $\mathcal{H}=\overline{\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}}\subseteq\overline{\text{span}}\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}$, I guess it doesn't matter?

Comment: If I could understand why "the elements of the form $a^\ast a$ are exactly the positive elements", then I see the rest based on your comment. But I don't understand the statement in quotes. EDIT: Actually, right after I wrote this, I think I see why. There is a theorem that says if $b\geq0$ then $b=a^\ast a$ for some $a\in A$. I suppose this is what is being used?

Comment: @D.Math Concerning your first comment: $\sum_i \lambda_i\pi(a_i) h = \pi(\sum_i \lambda_i a_i)h$ so no need to take the linear span :)

Comment: @D.Math Concerning your second comment: yes you are right. This is what is used.

Comment: Ah, so by your comment $\text{span}\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}=\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\}$? Also, I have a question about when the proof says "$\frac{1}{\|a\|^2}a^\ast a\leq\mathbf{1}_A$". Shouldn't we just have strict equality by the following: $a^\ast a$ is self adjoint and positive with $\|a^\ast a\|=\|a\|^2$ and hence $\left\|\frac{1}{\|a\|^2}a^\ast a\right\|=1$. There is a result that says for $a\in A$ positive self adjoint element, $a\leq\mathbf{1}_A$ iff $\|a\|\leq1$. So by this don't we have $\frac{1}{\|a\|^2}a^\ast a=\mathbf{1}_A$ and so $a^\ast a=\|a\|^2\mathbf{1}_A$?

Comment: @Yes, my comment implies that $\operatorname{span}\pi(A)h = \pi(A)h$. And for your second thing: no, this isn't true at all. Use the characterisation you mention: $\|\frac{a^*a}{\|a\|^2}\|=1$ so $\frac{a^*a}{\|a\|^2} \le 1$. 

Clearly, the equality $a^*a = \|a\|^2 1_A$ can't be right in general because it would imply that every positive element in a unital $C^*$-algebra is a multiple of the identity, which is very wrong.

Comment: I'm just not seeing how the characterisation I mentioned together with $\|\frac{a^\ast a}{\|a\|^2}\|=1$ implies $\frac{a^\ast a}{\|a\|^2}\leq\mathbf{1}_A$...could you spill the details for this, I suppose even more so than you have.

Comment: @D.Math I'm not sure what there is to explain: $\|\frac{a^*a}{\|a\|^2}\|=1\implies \|\frac{a^*a}{\|a\|^2}\|\le1\implies \frac{a^*a}{\|a\|^2}\le1_A$ where the last implication follows by your characterisation.

Comment: Oh, I figured that. But then I don't see why the case that $1_A\leq\frac{a^\ast a}{\|a\|^2}$ does not hold, although I see why if it did hold there would be a problem.

Comment: @D.Math I see no reason why this should hold, nor did you provide one.

Comment: My apologies, after trying to write out a proof, I see where I was making an implication that just simply wasn't true. Thank you for your answer, and helpful comments!

Comment: @D.Math Glad to be of assistance!

Comment: If you have a moment extra, could you check out section 3.1 of these notes:  https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf . The author defines nondegnerate and cyclic the way I wrote here as the closure of the span, so is this unnecessary in both cases, as you mentioned?

Comment: @D.Math You should add another question.

Comment: Just added a question relevant to the one I asked and about the one I posted.